# Syntax Error - collectionViewURL undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an iTunes Search App connecting the iTunes API. React is my FrontEnd and Express is my BackEnd
I have 4 files:

1. `Album.JS`
2. `Album_Search.JS`
3. `Favourites.js`
4. `Carousel.js`

When I connect to my React App I get the following: `[Error in Syntax][1]` I have been stuck for 2 days and cannot seem to resolve this issue in my code. Is anyone able to advise?

**In my Album.js file I am receiving the error in my return statement. My Syntax is listed below:**

```js
/* Connecting to React Library and My Components */ 

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';

/* Defining My Album Component */
class Album extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            names: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favouriteList")) || [],
        }
    }

    updateTodo = favouriteList => {
        this.setState({favouriteList});
    };

    updateLocalStorage = todoList => {
        localStorage.setItem("favouriteList", JSON.stringify(todoList));
    };

    // Refresh the Page and Load Session Storage 
    handleFavClicked = event => {
        window.location.reload()

        // Append any Favourite Item and add them to an Array 
        let favouriteItem = {};
        event.preventDefault();

        // Updating Session Storage and Storing the Favourite in the Store Favourites    Variable
        let storeFavourites = [];
        console.log(favouriteItem);

        let name = this.props.album.trackName
        let artistName = this.props.album.artistName
        let image = this.props.album.artworkUrl200
        let collectionViewUrl = this.props.album.collectionViewUrl


        const previousList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favouriteList"));
        if (previousList !== "" && Array.isArray(previousList)) {
            storeFavourites = [...previousList];
        }

        // Adding Information Relevant to the Item Returned in Search        
        favouriteItem = {name, artistName, image,collectionViewUrl};
        storeFavourites.push(favouriteItem);


        // Updating Local Storage
        console.log(storeFavourites);
        this.updateLocalStorage(storeFavourites);
        this.updateTodo(storeFavourites);
        alert(name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header style={styles.blockInline}>
                <a className="album-container" style={styles.album} href={this.props.album.collectionViewUrl}>
                    <div className="image-container" style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <img className="img-responsive" style={styles.image} src={this.props.album.artworkUrl200} 
                        alt={this.props.album.artistName}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="album-text" style={styles.albumText}>
                        <h5 className="name" style={styles.name}>
                            {this.props.album.artistName}
                        </h5>
                        <p className="description" style={styles.description}>
                            {this.props.album.trackName}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>  
                <button style={styles.button} className='myButton' onClick={this.handleFavClicked}>
                    Add to Favoutites
                </button>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Album;
```

Comment: What do you get in the console when you do `console.log(this.props.album.collectionViewUrl)`?

Comment: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'album' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:24 (anonymous) @ VM73:1

Comment: From the error you see that `album` isn't passed in as a `prop`.  Can you show how you pass the `album` into that component?

Comment: From the code Album is defined as the component.
I do not see any props defined in the first 4 lines of the code provided. 

Further down before the render method there are variables defined that relate to the items that must be returned to the user when searching for an album e.g image and artist name they past into props.album. album is not passing into any code at all.

Comment: From the code Album is defined as the component.
I do not see any props defined in the first 4 lines of the code provided. 

Further down before the render method there are variables defined that relate to the items that must be returned to the user when searching for an album e.g image and artist name they past into props.album. album is not passing into any code at all. The Variables mentioned above get used in the return statement. This is where the error then generates. of collectionViewURL not defined

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I am trying to understand why you are doing this `this.props.album` when the `album` is not passed into your component `<Album />`. Please show me where you are using this `<Album />` component

Comment: The code is above in the question

Comment: Where above? Okay sorry I can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Rotmi thank you it is fine. I will come right.